# Enumerate non-1 step in Power M List

Tags: powerbi, m

I know there is enumeration in list of Power M
for {1, 2, 3, ... 10} can be achieved by

```
{1..25}
```

What about {0, 25, 50, ... 250}
how can i enumerate every 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with:

```
List.Generate(() => 0, each _ > 250, each _ +25)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clue. the right code should be  List.Generate(() => 0, each _ < 250, each _ + 25)